# goto and automatic variables initializer in c

Tags: c

In a tutorial it said

**If you use the goto statement to jump into the middle of a block, automatic variables within that block are not initialized.**

Then in the below code if i can be accessed/declared then why it is not initialised?

```
int main()
{
   goto here;
   {
     int i=10;
     here:
      printf("%d\n",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**ps:output is some garbage value.**

Comment: Just write your initialisation explicitly, than it gets clearer: int i;i=10;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no logic behind your question "if `i` can be accessed, why...". Being able to "access `i`" isn't an argument for or against anything. It just means that the `printf` statement is in the same scope as `i`. However, since you jumped over the initializer, the variable is uninitialized (just as your tutorial says).

Reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour, so your program is ill-formed.

The memory for the variable `i` has already been set aside at compile time, since the variable is known to exist inside the inner block. The memory doesn't get allocated dynamically, as you may be imagining. It's already there, but it never got set to anything determinate because of the `goto`.

Rule of thumb: Don't jump across initializers.

Comment: When compiler compiles instructions will be something like this for the block, push i and then initializing instruction for i,then how push i is executed when goto statement makes it to jump to printf instruction directly?i couldnt understand that

Comment: thats interesting - so the compiler sees the statement int i=10; and allocates enough memory on the stack for an int but *doesn't* set it to 10. If the statement was split, e.g. int i; i=10; we could think of the compiler acting on the 1st statement but skipping the 2nd. This is a good question - gets you thinking

Comment: @Hiett: if it helps remember what's going on, variable declarations *are not statements* in the C grammar. All the declarations in a block contribute to the compiler's understanding of what space it needs to make available on the stack when code enters that block, which is sort of why in C89 they had to be at the start of the block, before any statements. Initializers for and assignments to those variables are treated somewhat separately from the knowledge that a total of (say) 4 bytes of automatic variables are called for.

Comment: @SteveJessop: great point, differentiating between declarations and statements is important in understanding whats going on - I think the confusion arises because you combine both a decalaration and a statement in the same line of code here, i.e. int i=10; leaves you thinking how can it do one bit of the line (the declaration) but not the other (the initialisation)

Comment: @vindhya: you could examine the emitted code if you can read assembly, but possibly what happens is that at the site of the `goto`, the compiler adjusts the stack pointer before jumping. Another possibility is that the compiler has actually "lifted" the space for the variable `i` outside the block, so that space is made for it at the start of the function, and the stack pointer is moved once on function entry, and then not moved again as you enter and leave the block.

Comment: @SteveJessop:could you please elaborate on last point you said about lifting the space for the variable?I could not understand that.

Comment: @vindhya: I mean that the definition `int i = 10;` might not emit code to move the stack by 4 bytes and then write 10 to that space, as you expected. It might cause the compiler to add 4 to however much it moves the stack by when it enters the function, and then emit the code to assign the value 10 at the place where the definition occurs. This is especially useful if there are loops in the function -- you could save two instructions per loop iteration if you avoid moving the stack pointer at every opportunity.

Comment: To clarify "memory for `i` has already been set aside at compile time" (could be misleading): `i` is a local variable for which space is created on the stack each time the function is called and the stack is restored when the function exits - the compiler added the code to create the space on the stack and replace the variable with the address of this space, in this case `[rbp-4]` where 4 is the size of int

Comment: @SteveJessop:thanks a lot.it was very informative and helpful.But could you explain how declarations are treated by compilers specially inside a block?sorry for being so naive?

Comment: Just as a nitpick, the behavior is only UB because the address of `i` is never taken, that is because it *could* have been declared with `register`. Generally uninitialized `auto` variables only lead to unspecified values.

Comment: @Jens: I'm curious, where does the standard say that if you never take the address of a variable (i.e. if the variable is eligible for `register`), then reading it uninitialized is UB? My understanding was that C++ explicitly states that reading an uninitialized object is UB, and C does not (you get an unspecified value, which depending on implementation details might cause UB but typically cannot). I've never heard this thing before about C *sometimes* yielding UB depending how the variable is used elsewhere.

Comment: @SteveJessop, it is in C11 6.3.2.1 p2: "If
the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been
declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object
is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @SteveJessop, ah, and the term that the standard applies is in 3.19.2 "**indeterminate value**
either an unspecified value or a trap representation"

Comment: @JensGustedt: thanks, I'll modify my list of strange ways that C and C++ differ. You're right, I meant indeterminate value rather than unspecified value.

Comment: And that text doesn't appear in C99, so presumably there's an optimization that was (in effect) forbidden in C99 but with is now permitted in C11, which is to register-ize a variable not declared `register`, with the consequence that something nasty happens when it's used uninitialized. Register-izing was OK in C99 only if it could still be read an yield an indeterminate value as opposed to disaster, and programs that relied on that in C99 now have UB in C11. But hurrah to C11 for formally defining "uninitialized", which C++ doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Variables are visible in the scope in which they are declared (between the `{}` in this case), irrespective of the order of execution of the statements within that scope. The `goto` bypasses the initialization of `i`, meaning it has an undefined value when the `printf()` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Consider another, obvious, situation:

```
int main()
{
    int i; //i is declared, but not initialized
    goto here;
    {
       i=10;//i is initialized 
       here: //you've skipped the initialization
       printf("%d\n",i);//and got garbage
    }
return 0;
}
```

In your case:

```
int main()
{

    goto here;
    {
       //printf("%d\n",i);  // i does not exist here yet
       int i; //from here until the end of the scope variable i exists
       i=10;  // i exists here and smth is written into it
   here:  // i exists here
       printf("%d\n",i); // i exists here and it's value is accessed
    }
return 0;
}
```

So, `int i = 5;` that's really 2 things. One is declaration, and is not skippable by anything, including `goto` (much like opening of a new scope is also unaffected. You;ve jumped into the middle of the scope, but the scope was already there). Second is operation assignment, and since it's normal operation (program flow) it can be skipped by `goto` or 'break' or 'continue', or 'return'

Comment: While I suspect that you are using "initialize" in a colloquial sense, c formally treats "assignment" and "initialization" as separate things even though they can both be indicated with a `=`. Just try `int a[3]; a = { 1, 2, 3};` as compared to `int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: @dmckee I've used "initialize" in a sense "assigning a value to a variable that was never assigned before and contains garbage". The array initializer is quite a hack and exception by itself. So leaving it out of consideration makes the image clearer.

Comment: I understood, but the standard uses the words "assignment" and "initialization" and in that formal context they are different. That's a pain when you're writing informally because there is always a risk of introducing confusion.

Comment: @dmckee The standard uses many words contrary to common sense and insists on calling UB on every other behavior that's perfectly defined by implementations. So IMHO standard is best used to dazzle internet opponents, not to actually help someone understand something.

Answer (score 0):

The C compiler will parse the source file and it "records" any variable initializations.
When it reaches

```
printf("%d\n", i)
```

it will know that the variable i already exists and he should be able to use it,  since it is in scope. 
At execution space is reserved for the i variable on the stack right after the call of the main function, and before any of the code in main() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the language standard says so:

**6.7.8 Initialization**

**Semantics**

If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

**J.2 Undefined behavior**

The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate.

**6.8.4.2 The switch statement**

EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment

```
switch (expr)
{
  int i = 4;
  f(i);
  case 0:
    i = 17;
    /* falls through into default code */
  default:
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

the object whose identifier is i exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the printf function will access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to the function f cannot be reached.

Comment: Appendix J is only informative. Actually 6.3.2.1 p2 (according to C11) is more precise and normative. It is only UB if the `auto` variable could have been declared with `register`, that is its address is never taken.

Comment: @JensGustedt The value is still indeterminate and it's better to avoid even a potential UB.

Comment: On most architectures (that don't have trap representations) it is just an unspecified value, which should already be bad enough to convince everybody, not to do such things :)

Comment: @JensGustedt I know, ditto with signed overflows.

Answer (score -1):

C lets you access anything within your address space, whether it's actually initialized or not. Sometimes working like that crashes or shows garbage, sometimes it happens to print something useful, but it's all undefined behavior. Handy trick, but a great way to break your program, so don't think that just getting a result means your trick works.

Comment: Surely C doesn't "let you access anything anywhere".

Comment: You can put a pointer to any number you want into printf, and it'll happily print the contents of that memory location as if it was a local variable. Maybe I should have qualified with "within your address space" but surely you know what I meant?

Comment: Variables are still scoped, so it's not like many other languages where everything you ever defined is readable from anywhere else. You still have to play by the rules. Also, there are strict rules for pointer semantics, and you're most likely talking about some sort of undefined behaviour...

Comment: If you write `return i;` instead of `return 0;` in the questioner's code, then C doesn't let you access anything anywhere. The question seems to be about how `i` can be in scope yet uninitialized, rather than about C's generous offer to you to shoot yourself in the foot by using pointers to roam around the address space :-)

Comment: Surely C lets you access anything with a pointer (within your address space...), but that is not the point of the question. There are no pointers involved, just "normal" variables. So accessing the variable is not a trick, it is just accessing a variable. The jump over the initialisation is bad...

Comment: Well, I was just trying to explain *why* he still happened to get a result when he probably expected a compiler error. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Your answer has to be read a little bit more common, which is good in a sense. I upvoted it.